# Modify hyperlinks in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I'm using `hyperref` package so that `\tableofcontents` has clickable links.

Is there a way to force **one** hyperlink in `\tableofcontents` to refer to a given page instead of the automatically selected page?

Say you have a chapter beginning on page 2 of your PDF output but you want table of contents to create a corresponding clickable link that displays page 3 instead.

(I am looking for a general answer here, hence the absence of code/header)

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but it's confusing, isn't it?

Comment: Louis, I fear, I will provide some work and you will delete the question after some minutes, as you have done with the other ones. ;-)

Comment: Although your question is `general`, you should give a rule what to do actually. What is the rule for another chapter? Is it the second page of the chapter too then?

Comment: Poorly asked, well, yes and no -- they weren't just incomplete and nobody could make out of nothing then...

Comment: Yes, but which given page??? Just for one single page then?

Comment: The hyperlinks in the TOC are there to go to the start of the respective part of the text. I don't see why you'd want them to point elsewhere (except for making fun of your readers...). If you want some Table of Whatever pointing at other parts of the text, there mostly are ways to point at e.g. figures, tables in the respective table.

Comment: Guys, I'm not looking for explanations that this is confusing or useless. Just a solution to modify one hyperlink in the table of contents.

Comment: If nobody else finds a solution, I will try later on

Comment: Fixing wrong anchors is usually much easier than fixing wrong link targets. A `\phantomsection` at the right place or using `\refstepcounter` instead `\stepcounter` might already solve the issue.

Comment: @Louis: It's no fun to programme it either. See my possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I've misunderstood the question anyway completely:

There should be a `hyperlink` looking like a chapter entry but not to the start page of the chapter, pointing to somewhere else.

I've done a `\nottocchapter` which behaves like an usual numbered chapter, but kicked out `\addcontentsline` there.

Then I defined `\lookslikeachapterentrybutpointstosomewhereelse` (that name is a pain for users misusing the appropiate thing ;-)) which adds the relevant chapter entry later on, with the page number where it appears.

Do I recommend this all? No ;-)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xparse}


\makeatletter

\let\latex@chapter\chapter

\def\currentchaptername{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\notocchapter}{om}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \def\currentchaptername{#1}
  }{%
    \def\currentchaptername{#2}
  }%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}% Do nothing for this chapter
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \latex@chapter[#1]{#2}
  }{%
    \latex@chapter{#2}
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lookslikeachapterentrybutpointstosomewhereelse}{o}{%
  \phantomsection
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
  }{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\currentchaptername}
  }%
}

\makeatother

\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\notocchapter{Some chapter}

\blindtext[20] 

\lookslikeachapterentrybutpointstosomewhereelse

\chapter{Some other chapter}

\notocchapter{Another chapter}

\blindtext[40] 

\lookslikeachapterentrybutpointstosomewhereelse[And now for something completely different]


\end{document}
```

Comment: I've omitted a screenshot

Comment: @Mico: ;-) You know me -- About one quarter of my answers contain that line :-P

Comment: I thought it's particularly appropriate in this context. :-)